How to differentiate between broken setup and invalid token?
I'm using JOSE4J to process a token to JWT claims like
final var jwtClaim = new JwtConsumerBuilder()
                .setVerificationKeyResolver(
                        new HttpsJwksVerificationKeyResolver(
                                new HttpsJwks(getFfgTemplateUrl())))
                .setExpectedIssuer(getBiasUrl())
                .setSkipDefaultAudienceValidation()
                .build()
                .processToClaims(token);

If something goes wrong then a InvalidJwtException is thrown. This is usually mapped then to a 401 response or so.
However, in case of some kind of setup-error how can I differentiate between just invalid token and all other kind of errors that may or may not happen?
